# Why is text not added to forest plot in R metafor-package?

Tags: r, plot, metafor

My data:

```
dat <- structure(list(study = structure(c(2L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("Ansari et al.", "De Santis et al.", "Dewan et al.", "Garbossa et al.", "lockney et al", "Sughrue et al. ", "Wu et al."), class = "factor"), year = c(2002L, 2011L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2017L, 2017L), event.e = c(13L, 0L, 15L, 8L, 34L, 17L, 8L), n.e = c(100L, 129L, 61L, 43L, 134L, 301L, 162L), event.c = c(11L, 1L, 11L, 9L, 12L, 1L, 9L), n.c = c(100L, 51L, 62L, 48L, 68L, 41L, 234L), ntotal = c(200L, 180L, 123L, 91L, 202L, 342L, NA), yi = structure(c(0.167054084663166, -2.02071136213801, 0.32641544917562, -0.00778214044205483, 0.363121780053356, 0.839675146011648, 0.249941744468934), measure = "OR", ni = c(224L, 181L, 149L, 108L, 248L, 360L, 413L)), vi = c(0.187832167832168, 2.69380615011683, 0.190098232456773, 0.280200258397933, 0.134913666959321, 1.08653603245042, 0.246557454890788), author = structure(c(2L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("Ansari et al.", "De Santis et al.", "Dewan et al.", "Garbossa et al.", "lockney et al", "Sughrue et al. ", "Wu et al."), class = "factor")), .Names = c("study", "year", "event.e", "n.e", "event.c", "n.c", "ntotal", "yi", "vi", "author"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), digits = 4, yi.names = "yi", vi.names = "vi", class = c("escalc", "data.frame"))
```

I use the metafor-package to conduct my meta-analysis. I want to add some text to my Forest Plot as "head labels" for the plot figure. 
I have followed the metafor-guide but the text it is not added. I cant figure out why.

My Forest Plot:

```
library(metafor)
par(mar=c(4,4,1,2))

res <- rma(yi, vi, data=dat, slab=paste(author, year, sep=", "))

tmp <- cumul(res, order=order(dat$year))

forest(tmp, xlim=c(-4,2), at=log(c(0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2)), 
atransf=exp, digits=c(2,3), cex=0.75)

par(cex=0.75, font=2)

text(-4, 15, "Author(s) and Year", pos=4)
text( 2, 15, "Odds Ratio [95% CI]", pos=2)
```

My Forest Plot looks like this:

[image: Forest Plot without text]

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance,
C.

Comment: Because `15` is way too large. Try `8` or `9` for the second value in `text()`.

Comment: @Wolfgang do you mind posting as an answer?

Comment: @zx8754 Sure thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of `text()` specifies the y-axis position of where the text should be added. You specified `15` for that, but that is outside of the plot limits. Setting the value to `8` or `9` should be appropriate here.